# I don’t understand what a hot-swappable battery is

Tags: power-supply, batteries

Some time ago, my dad bought a [60V 30AH hot-swappable battery](https://www.swapbatterystation.com/product/60v-30ah-hot-swap-battery/). After working on it for a long time, I couldn't figure out what it was used for. Many results found online were conflicting. So I came here to ask for advice. What is a hot-swappable battery?

Comment: "Hot-swappable" just means something that can be removed and replaced while whatever it's plugged into is powered up. What does it fit into?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why did you receive this battery in the first place, just something to play with? From the link it looks like it's for EV.

Comment: What did "*working on it for a long time*" incorporate?

Comment: @Finbarr "Hot swap" is usually applied to more internal things rather than simple plugs.

Answer (score 6):

It's a commercial slogan. This video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6A_dBYTGSk0 shows its practical meaning in this context. The term is borrowed from computer and digital communication technology. Complex data server and communication systems have often hot swappable component modules like power supplies, disks, processing CPUs, data transmission switches, radio transmitters etc... That's because hot swappable parts can be plugged out and replaced without turning the rest of the system OFF. That's quite a vital property in systems which must run with no break, no matter a single component may have a failure. The repairman simply comes and replaces the module which has stopped working perfectly or has reached the end of its calculated reliable working life.

Most of us have hot swappable things. We only do not think it. We use one for example when we plug something to an USB connector or pull it out.

Why it is not called "hot plug"? It was, but the inventor of the term trademarked it in 1990s, so the others had to find a new slogan.

Designing something in a computer system be hot swappable is far from trivial. The shortest wrong connection, a wrong connecting order, plugging in a wrong or faulty part and static electricity discharges can all be fatal. They simply should not happen or the system must tolerate them. It's a system wide design challenge.

The electric motorbike in the linked video has 2 batteries in parallel. They can be swapped to fully charged ones in a battery swapping station even without turning the bike OFF (I bet one must still stop driving for a moment).

The linked video is quite interesting. Having numerous high energy vehicle batteries (in unknown condition) under charging in the same cabinet is not an activity that I would like to have in my home. The video says that no worry, the fans keep it cool and if it happens to catch a fire, the included (in production models only) waterbank beats the problem soon. And a full manual is included, so everyone fixes any faults easily.

Comment: The idea of a waterbank system for high energy vehicle battery fires (where you are dealing with a lithium fire) seems highly questionable.

Comment: @danstenius You seem to have employed a certain amount of sarcasm and innuendo in your answer, which makes it unclear and prone to misinterpretation.

Comment: @Sneftel maybe you show where I have spred some lies about the video.

Comment: @danstenius What are you talking about?

Answer (score 5):

Hot swap is when you don't need to care for to de-/energize the circuit before a battery is to be removed or inserted, like for example flip a switch. The hot swap function itself is doing that.